Can difference version of ros2 communicate with each other?
I'd like to check if I use some specific DDS, like fastdds, or cyclonedds, can ROS2 humble on one PC communicate with ROS2 Jazz on the other PC?

I've tried this before and I've empirically observed it to work with basic topic publication and subscription. That said, mixing ROS distributions is not recommended or officially supported:
https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/issues/3288#issue-1557321305

And the answer is NO for both cases. currently ROS 2 does not support any cross-distro or cross-vendor communication officially. (which is my understanding, if i am mistaken, let me know) some of these cases are implemented in test code, but that does not mean that we support these compatibility.

The rest of that discussion thread has a lot of good information.
From https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-2-tsc-meeting-minutes-2023-02-16/29927, some clear guidance:

Cross Distro – might break API / ABI – this is a bad

Surprising this works but can break in really subtle ways

Chris et al are working on a potential solution but this will not land in Iron.

No testing of cross distro

Chris: This needs to be documented - but we need to make it very very clear that it is bad, but you
can work around it in exceptional cases.

Kat: Official policy is that cross distro is bad and will not work




